# Exception could not understand in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, exception

Hey can anyone help me out that what type of exception is this i had earlier a code and link is as: [Application run on simulator but not on device in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800108/application-run-on-simulator-but-not-on-device-in-iphone?noredirect=1#comment31183474_20800108)

can anybody here who can tell that what type of exception is in it? is there any memory leak?

here is the log below:

```
 2013-12-27 17:53:26.814 Skirr[1346:a0b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
2013-12-27 17:53:27.995 Skirr[1346:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x032745e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x021b88b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x03228316 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 390
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0324bce9 +[NSArray arrayWithObject:] + 73
    4   Skirr                               0x000093bd -[SlideViewController viewDidLoad] + 1597
    5   UIKit                               0x00e2d318 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    6   UIKit                               0x00e2d5b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    7   UIKit                               0x00e473e2 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 778
    8   UIKit                               0x00e540c7 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
    9   UIKit                               0x00e54cb9 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    10  UIKit                               0x00f8e181 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    11  UIKit                               0x00d84267 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x021ca81f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    13  QuartzCore                          0x005622ea -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    14  QuartzCore                          0x005560d4 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    15  QuartzCore                          0x00555f40 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    16  QuartzCore                          0x004bdae6 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    17  QuartzCore                          0x004bee71 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    18  QuartzCore                          0x004bf544 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0323c4ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0323c41f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0321a344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x03219ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x032198db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x034ce9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x034ce809 GSEventRun + 104
    26  UIKit                               0x00d19d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    27  Skirr                               0x000055a2 main + 130
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x06896725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Please also share the function -[SlideViewController viewDidLoad].

Comment: The actual crash is when you attempt to put `nil` into an array inside a call to `initWithObjects:count:`.  (According to the messages, you also have a problem with setting up your initial view controller.)

Comment: Note, this is the error message for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800108/application-run-on-simulator-but-not-on-device-in-iphone/20800940#20800940), the OP posted the error message in a new question instead of adding it to the original question.

Comment: @PhillipMills, right but in simulator array is not found nil it is only in device here is the link you would get the actual problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800108/application-run-on-simulator-but-not-on-device-in-iphone

Comment: Since that error is in relation to the question you have already asked you shouldn't be re-asking the question

Comment: Your error occurs on this line `[_slideNavigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:initalViewController] animated:NO];` your `initalViewController` is `nil` so it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

have look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw) from

> attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

you are inserting or handling nil object you can get that line refer given above link

Answer (score 0):

The error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

is occurring because you are trying to add `nil` value to an `NSArray`. After looking through your code on the other question the specific line of code that it is crashing on is

```
[_slideNavigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:initalViewController] animated:NO];
```

It is crashing here because of one of two things

1) `initalViewController` is `nil` so when you add it using `arrayWithObject` it crashes.

or

2) `setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:initalViewController]` is causing the error because `[NSArray arrayWithObject:initalViewController]` is setting `nil` to the method `setViewControllers:` method which takes an `NSArray`.

I would say it is option (1) that is causing your issue though as the crash happens when `arrayWithObject` is called.

Comment: But in simulator it is running perfectly.but in device it's not why?

Comment: Hard to tell really without more information but `        UIViewController *initalViewController = [self.delegate initialViewController];` is definitely nil.

Comment: yeah in device its nil but in simulator how can i make you to find me the solution please eat some spinach and help me

Comment: There isn't much else I can tell from your code. You will have to add some breakpoints and cycle through your code dropping into methods until you find out where exactly it is. What I have included in my answer is all based on the error and code you have provided.

Answer (score -1):

Check your main.m. The last argument should be set to the name of the class that implements the UIApplicationDelegate protocol OR you can try for last argument like `NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])`.

Please check this link it might help you .
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati)

Comment: How is this connected to the exception in the question?

Comment: Yurish please see the very first line of crash log.

Comment: It's about a root view controller, not about the app delegate.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the crash. That first line is more of a warning which will not crash the app at the very least it will just provide a blank screen but it will still run. The second line in the crash log is the error that is causing the crash. This has nothing to do with `AppDelegate` in main.m -1 as incorrect.

Comment: It is pretty clear that `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'` is the issue that crashes the app. Notice the words **Terminating app due to uncaught exception ...**

Comment: `4   Skirr                               0x000093bd -[SlideViewController viewDidLoad] + 1597` this line  show actual crash the app.`SlideViewController ` view even not properly load.

Comment: @RahulShrimali you added any conditional code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to launch the app ?

Comment: @prashant So what does that have to do with main.m? The error occurs in `-[SlideViewController viewDidLoad]` `viewDidLoad` being the method being called. At which point in that method this `+[NSArray arrayWithObject:]` is being called `arrayWithObjects`. So when this is being called they are trying to add a `nil` value to the array which is being accepted.Which is the reason for `attempt to insert nil object` So this has nothing to do with what your answer is talking about in main.m.

Comment: Also who cares what happens in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` they need to be pointing a breakpoint in the `viewDidLoad` in `SlideViewController`. Really all they need to do is look for where the array is being created in `viewDidLoad` and stick a breakpoint at that array.

Comment: There error occurs on `[_slideNavigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:initalViewController] animated:NO];` which is being called in `viewDidLoad` the `initalViewController` is `nil`.

Comment: @Rahul please check the above link which help you a lot.