# Ordered comparison between pointer and integer iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using two DatePicker in CustomViewController and after calculating get the value of difference between two dates.which is calculated .now in another controller I have to put date value into a label.

Value in label should be in integer form.but what I have to do is if the value is <=5 days then it should be show in red color, if value is <=8 days then it should be in yellow and finally if >=8 then green color should be appear in label.

So I am not getting that how I put conditional statement so I can move on.I already done calculation part.

Here is my code where I get this warning:

```
int i = 5;
if (cell.lblDate.text <=i) {
    cell.lblDate.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "order" between an integer and a pointer.  If you want to do that comparison, compare to `cell.lblDate.text.integerValue`.

Comment: (And *please* spend a little more time learning basic C before continuing with Objective-C.  You're going to develop some expensive bad habits and misconceptions if you don't.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
int i = 5;
if ([cell.lblDate.text  integerValue] <= i) {
    cell.lblDate.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: Thanks brother ..can you help me for one thing also...please

Comment: Yes. ask your question by updating your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800108/application-run-on-simulator-but-not-on-device-in-iphone please check this link i have tried so many time but no one understood that my application is running perfectly on simulator but not on device its crash please suggest